# Is my proof correct? prove ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have proofed a statement (tried) but im not sure if my proof is 100 % correct.

"Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $c \in \mathbb{F}$. Prove that

$$ \phi : \mathbb{F}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{F}[x] $$

$$\phi (\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^{i}) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i(x+c)^i$$

is a ring isomorphism."

Here is my attempt of a proof.

Let $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^{i} \in \mathbb{F}[x], \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_kx^{k} \in \mathbb{F}[x]$.

$$ \phi( \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^{i} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_kx^{k})=$$
/Now assume that $m>n$ hence $a_i=0 $, $\forall i>n$/
$$ =\phi( \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_kx^{k} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_kx^{k})=$$

$$=\phi ( \sum\limits_{k=0}^m (a_k+b_k)x^{k}) =  \sum\limits_{k=0}^m (a_k+b_k)(x+c)^{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_k(x+c)^{k} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_k(x+c)^{k} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i(x+c)^{i} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_k(x+c)^{k} = \phi (\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^{i}) + \phi ( \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_kx^{k})$$

---

$$\phi(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^{i} \cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_kx^{k})=
 \phi (\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_ix^{i}b_kx^{k}) =$$
/ $\mathbb{F}$ Is a field/
$$= \phi(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_ib_kx^{k+i})= $$
/Assume $m>n$, hence $a_i=0$ $\forall i>n$/
$$=\phi(\sum\limits_{k=0,i=0}^m a_ib_kx^{i+k}) =  \sum\limits_{k=0,i=0}^m a_ib_k(x+c)^{i+k} = \sum\limits_{k=0,i=0}^m a_i(x+c)^{i}b_k(x+c)^{k} =
\sum\limits_{i=0}^m a_i(x+c)^{i} \cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_k(x+c)^{k} = 
\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i(x+c)^{i} \cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_k(x+c)^{k}=$$
$$=\phi(\sum\limits_{i=0}^m a_ix^{i}) \cdot \phi (\sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_kx^{k})$$

---

Assume $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^{i} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_kx^{k} \Leftrightarrow$ 
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i(x+c)^{i} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_k(x+c)^{k}$$

Two polynomial are equal if the have the same degree and same koefficients, hence $m=n$ and $b_k=a_i$, hence $\phi$ is injective. Finally $\phi$ is surjective by definition, $\phi$ is a ring isohomorphism.

---

I am not comfortable with all the rules of sumes, and double sumes, therefor I am insecure of my proof. I have done my steps on intuition, therefor I can not confirm that my steps are correct.